# Changing ControlTemplate when button clicked Wpf

Tags: python, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, mvvm

I have the following simple XAML file:

```
<Window 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       Title="WpfApplication4" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="simpleErrorTemplate">
            <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="T1" />
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="detailedErrorTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="T2" />
                <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="T3" />
                <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="T4" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Setter Property="Template"
                        Value="{StaticResource simpleErrorTemplate}"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button,Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource detailedErrorTemplate}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
        <Button x:Name="Button" Content="Button" Height="40" Width="129" Margin="88,5,76,5" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What it does is that it changes the template when the button is pressed. 
However, I want it to happen once I clicked, without the need of holding it pressed.

1) Is there any trigger from the click style so the moment I clicked it will call the trigger?

2) In the code-behind file, I had like it to run a function the moment I clicked the button and only afterwards to change the template since it is using data from the first template.

```
import wpf

from System.Windows import Application, Window
from scores import score

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ui = wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication1.xaml')

    def Button_Click1(self, sender, e):
        x = score(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

So eventually my goal is to click Button, to calculate the function score and only then to change the template.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: why not using a toggle button? it has `IsChecked`

Comment: Because this is a simple example. My real GUI is basically a login screen when you write name and once you click on login I want it to change the template. wont look so nice with toggle button.

Comment: then you'll need to use a boolean. I see no other way

Comment: Can you please give me an idea where to use this boolean? on what property?

Comment: sure @Ben, see the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Define a DependencyProperty in MyWindow: (MyWindow.xaml.cs)

```
    public bool MyBoolean
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(MyBooleanProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyBooleanProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyBooleanProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyBoolean", typeof(bool), typeof(MyWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

This boolean **must** be set to true when the button is clicked.

Then name your MyWindow:

```
<Window x:Name="root"
        .../>
```

Then your trigger would be like:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=root,Path=MyBoolean}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource detailedErrorTemplate}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and im sure it work using c#, only thing im using wpf project in ironpython and from what I know its impossible to use this syntax mate. but thanks again.